# Solr Range Query multiple Columns

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a table:
Column Name: client-id Data Type: String
Column Name: start Data Type: Int
Column Name: end Data Type: Int

Sample Data:

### Column client-id  | start| end

```
     a        | 1    | 5
     b        | 7    | 10
```

Request would come with a random number: say 4

I have to check with Solr query if this range would fall within a range. For example, here it falls between 1 and 5 thus should return client-id 'a'.

My Solr query works but want to know if it can be improved:

solr_query='{"q":"end:[4 TO *] AND start:[* TO 4]}';

Comment: What do you want to improve if it works as you want it to?

Comment: Execution time.